# 2 pages, one renders and one does not, both in same directory

Tags: php, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have 2 pages on my report website that are not acting the same. I am using DataTables Server Side processing. The first page has only 74 rows returned (I know it doesn't really need to use server side processing) and the other page has more than 30,000+ rows with 65+ columns. The first page renders just fine, the second says that it can't find the page.

**EDIT**

How the pages are loaded:

1. Call to *ReportPage.php*
2. `included` file *ContentSearchpage.php* counts how many columns will be returned and how many rows. (not entirely sure that i still need this part, but havn't removed it yet)
3. `included` file *DBConn.php* has all the connection info for connecting to my SQL DB
4. create table with just the `thead` and `tfoot`, with all the `<th></th>` filled out based on the columns returned from the list I keep in my SQL DB
5. DataTables are initialized as shown below by sending the data to the server for processing using the file *ServerSide.PHP*
6. *ServerSide.php* sends the collected info to *FilterSort.class.php* which is what is used on the server to process the data and return a JSON string
7. DataTables jquery formats the returned JSON string into a table

This is how I'm initializing the pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        console.log("Test");
        $('#DataTable').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                            });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100, 150], [25, 50, 75, 100, 150]],
            "ScrollX": true,
            "dom": '<"top"Biflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
            "buttons": [
                {extend: 'collection', text: 'Selection', buttons: ['selectAll', 'selectNone']},
                {extend: 'collection', text: 'Export', buttons: ['excel', 'csv', 'pdf']}],
            "fixedHeader": {header: true, footer: false},
            "select": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {"url": "ServerSide.php?PageName=<?php echo $Page; ?>"}
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is how I'm starting the pages:

```
<h1>
    <?php
    echo $HeadingDesc;
    if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/",1) > 0)
    {
        echo "<br>Dev Site";
    }
    ?>
</h1>
<?php
//echo "<br>PageName: " . $Page;
//include('ContentPage.php');
//var_dump($Page);
//include ('Selected.php');
//var_dump($Page);
/* if(($Page == 'COEI_OPR' || $Page == 'OSP_OPR' || $Page == 'MaterialTracking' || $Page == 'MaterialReceived' || $Page == 'ApprovedProjects_PrevDay' || $Page == 'ApprovedProjects' || $Page == 'M6Action' || $Page == 'OPR_COEI' || $Page == 'OPR_OSP'))// && !isset($_GET['Project']))
  {
  require_once 'SearchTerm.php';
  //include 'ContentSearchPage.php';
  include 'DBConn.php';
  }
  else
  { */
include 'ContentSearchPage.php';
include 'DBConn.php';

$getHeadings   = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings     = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$CountHeadings = count($rHeadings);
//print_r($hsql);
$tsqlHeadings  = '';
for ($row = 0; $row < $CountHeadings; $row++)
{
    $headings[$row] = $rHeadings[$row]["Headings"];
    $tsqlHeadings   = $tsqlHeadings."[".$headings[$row].'],';
}

if ($DataTable == 1)
{
    $CountTSQL = "Select count(*) ".$tsql;
    $tsql      = "Select ".substr($tsqlHeadings,0,strlen($tsqlHeadings) - 1).$tsql;
}
else
{
    $CountTSQL = "Select count(*) ".$tsql;
    $tsql      = "Select ".substr($tsqlHeadings,0,strlen($tsqlHeadings) - 1).$tsql." order by Id OFFSET $offset ROWS FETCH NEXT $limit ROWS ONLY";
}
?>
<table id="DataTable" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%; border: 1px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($headings as $heading)
            {
                ?>
                <th class="cell"><?php echo $heading; ?></th>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($headings as $heading)
            {
                ?>
                <th class="cell">
                    <?php echo $heading; ?>
                </th>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<?php //}    ?>
</body>
```

The *ContentSearchPage.php*:

```
<?php
case 'MaterialTrackingAll':
try
{
    include 'SearchParameters.php';
    include 'DBConn.php';

    $OneButton = 1;
    $Edit      = 0;
    $SQLArray  = array ("searchState" => $searchState,"searchProject" => $searchProject);

    $CountSQL    = "select count(*) from pmdb.v_MaterialTracking_OPCEN";
    $TotalRows   = $conn->query($CountSQL)->fetchColumn();
    $offset      = '';
    $currentpage = '';
    $DataTable   = 1;

    $tsql = " FROM pmdb.v_MaterialTracking_OPCEN";
    $hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'v_MaterialTracking_OPCEN' order by ID";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
}
break;
case 'QDefs':
try
{
    include 'SearchParameters.php';
    include 'DBConn.php';
    $Edit      = 1;
    $OneButton = 1;
    $SQLArray  = array ("searchState" => $searchState,"searchProject" => $searchProject);

    $CountSQL  = "select count(*) from pmdb.v_QDefs";
    $TotalRows = $conn->query($CountSQL)->fetchColumn();
    if ($TotalRows > 500)
    {
        include 'NavButtons.php';
        $DataTable = 0;
    }
    elseif ($TotalRows <= 500)
    {
        $offset      = '';
        $currentpage = '';
        $DataTable   = 1;
    }
    $tsql = " from pmdb.v_QDefs";
    $hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'v_QDefs' and Headings != 'Edit' order by Id";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
}
break;
?>
```

And the file *ServerSide.php* is just a modified version of the file that calls the *ssp.class.php* from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html), and I modified the *[ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)* so that it uses PDO::SQLSRV instead of MySql.

I can run the first page just fine, the table comes up and is workable. The second table does not come up. I only get the header and then a message that says:

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: My guess is that you have copied the second file so its permissions not allow reading or execution for the www-user. That could be, if you have copied the file using a filereader which itself have inadequate permissions.

Comment: @davidkonrad If that was the case then I wouldn't have a table for either page. They both use the same set of files. I updated my questions to hopefully clarify this. The only thing that changes between the different pages is the `PageName` that is sent to the *ServerSide.php* file, which is used as the SQL table name for getting data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.

I was sending everything through `$_GET`. The length of what I was sending exceeded the limit and so it would fail. I changed the way it is sent and am now using `$_POST` so send the data. The tables are now rendering as they should.

```
"ajax" : {
      "url" : "./ServerSide.php",
      "type": "POST"
     }
```